# Error while running the code source_file.java:15: error: unreachable statement System.out.println(i);} ^ 1 error

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    continue;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I want to understand the logic behind the error.

Comment: `continue` would force loop to skip rest of code from current iteration. This means that `System.out.println(i)` will never be executed so it is "dead code".

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `System.out.println(i);` before `continue` statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    continue;
}
```

Continue tells `for` loop to keep on and breaks the current iteration, so in your version `System.out.println(i)` is not reachable.

***Option***: You can omit `continue` as it is redundant being last statement in the loop (@Pshemo)

Comment: OR in this case we can simply remove `continue;` since as last statement in the loop it is redundant.

Comment: yeah that is also true.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `continue` means to skip the rest of the code in the loop and re-iterate. That means `System.out.println(i)` will never be reached. So to fix it, you could either move that line before `continue` or you can just delete that line.